# When is the youtube watermark added when embedding youtube through external third party players (jwplayer i.e.))

Tags: youtube, jwplayer, watermark, video-watermarking

This is just basically a personal tutorial or hack-challenge you could say for myself to understand certain things about youtube. My ultimate goal would be to be able to remove that youtube watermark in the bottom right corner. And yes, I know this in theory would go against their terms of service, but it's just for personal use, hack-challenge as explained earlier ;)

So when I embed a youtube video with an external third party player like jwplayer, at which point is that watermark added? Does the player do it or does youtube do it at their end before the player even receives the file from the youtube servers??

Comment: When the JW Player is used, the watermark is added as soon as play is pressed, because we use their official API, which has the watermark included.

Comment: but is that watermark part of the video? is it a sneeky placed html element? Does the jwplayer core ad it to the video file or does youtube ad it? i'm confused. Thank you for your reply anyway!

Comment: YouTube adds it. It is part of their API. It inside of their SWF file.

Comment: so i'd need to manipulate your player in touching the youtube api slightly different I guess

Comment: The API that is loaded in AS3 has the Watermark *built in*. You can't modify it.

Comment: well then it's not possible I agree. Thank you for your replies! :)

Comment: Yes, it is not possible. Np.